# Devolver Booleano en SELECT

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, spring, jpa

Tengo una entidad llamada "Periodo" con un atributo boolean llamado "procesando". Quiero hacer una función para un repositorio que devuelva "true" si hay al menos un registro en la DB con el atributo "procesando en true", sin embargo no estoy muy seguro de cómo hacerlo con Jpa, esto es lo que he intentado :

```
public interface PeriodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Periodo, Long> 
{

    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT P FROM Periodo P WHERE 
    P.procesando = false ) THEN CAST(0 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(1 AS BIT) END")
    public boolean isPeriodoProcesando();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

podrías regresar un Booleano en lugar de un Bit

```
public interface PeriodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Periodo, Long> 
{
    @Query("SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT P FROM Periodo P WHERE 
    P.procesando = false ) THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE 
    END")
    public boolean isPeriodoProcesando();
}
```